# my rspec output is so long it pushes the error out of view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Forgive me, I'm just trying to learn to test, but i know this is ridiculous. Anyone know what could be causing this?

I'm following along at devwalks.com and I'm on the part one of the testing track.

```
Failures:

  1) Creating posts Can create a job
     Failure/Error: visit '/'
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template posts/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/Andy/Desktop/rails/phototest/app/views"
     # /Users/Andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/ <-- this line repeats around 50 times with different subfolders/files 

Finished in 0.03078 seconds (files took 2.7 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure, 1 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/creating_posts_spec.rb:4 # Creating posts Can create a job
```

edit: solved

I just needed to delete

```
./spec/helpers/posts_helper_spec.rb:14

./spec/models/post_spec.rb:4
```

Comment: ... Scroll back to the error.

Comment: (And what are you actually asking? The title says one thing, the question text something else.)

Answer (score 0):

If you run rspec with the `-b` option it will give a full backtrace:

```
bundle exec rspec -b spec/features/creating_posts_spec.rb:4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as the error states: You don't have the posts/index view yet. Try adding app/views/posts/index.html.erb to your application

Comment: I've already fixed that error, I guess what I'm really asking is if there's a way to run rspec without getting 50+ lines of things I don't need to see. The error isn't the problem.